# Proof that there are Countably infinite Infinities

Tags: set-theory

Consider $N = \{0, 1, 2, 3,\ldots\}$ is defined by a "start" element (0) which is "less" than any other, and a Function $F_{N \to {N+1}}$ at which $F(n) = n+1$. so the natural numbers is a set with a start and a notion of next with no "last".
considering $0 = \{\} = \emptyset$ and $F(n) = \{0, 1, 2, 3, ..., n\}$ gives us a "new" element.

Now consider $N$ itself and $P(s) = \{powerset \space of \space s\}$
given N as the "starting" element and P(s) as the function it should be clear that size of all infinities is the same as size of $N$

i understand cardinality is only defined for sets and not proper classes but "if" the class of all infinite sets is a set, then it should have the same cardinality of $N$.

Comment: yeah i figured that's why i posted it here, i would like to know where i'm wrong ?

Comment: $N$ has an uncountable infinity of subsets. It's not at all clear to me why you think otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument shows that there are infinitely many infinities, but nothing more. To show why, let's find an infinity not in your construction.

Let $F$ be the binary relation (which is a proper class) such that $F(0)=\mathbb N$, and $F(n+1)=\mathcal P(F(n))$.

By the axiom schema of replacement applied to the set $\mathbb N$ with the map $F$, the object you construct is not a proper class, but instead a set. Thus, the union of the object has a cardinality greater than any particular element in the set (prove this if you don't believe it), which implies that there is a cardinality you haven't accounted for.

Comment: i've read up and thought about it for a while and i've found this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe) which has the same definition as your object and it's supposed to be the proper class of all well-founded sets and not a set
but your proof seems sound to me except the part which says the new object is a set
thank you for your time :)

Comment: @pomid Von Neumann's rank hierarchy is a larger construction than mine, thus why it is a class and not a set. But yes.